# How can I resolve data for all states with Angular UI Router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my application every route requires that account data has been retrieved from my API prior to rendering. To accomplish this, I do the following using ngRoute:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
    next.$$route.resolve = next.$$route.resolve || {};

    next.$$route.resolve.authorizationCheck = function() {
        return deferredAccountData.promise;
    };
});
```

So before each route, the `authorizationCheck` resolve, which returns a promise, must resolve. This works perfectly.

I'm now switching to using UI Router, and I need to preserve this functionality. What are some options for accomplishing this?

One option I can think of is using nested states and having all routes inherit resolves from a parent state. Though I'd prefer to not nest if possible. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could resolve the data you want for multiple ui-router states in a parent state. The child state would then have this data as well.

```
$stateProvider
.state('app', {
  url: "/",
  resolve: {
    authorizationCheck: function() {
       // Do your API checks or whatever
    }
  }
})
.state('app.somepage', {
  url: "/somepage",
  templateUrl: "partials/some.page.html",
  controller: function($scope) {

  }
})
```

It would make more sense to have authorization checks within a Service though, so you might want to inject an Auth service in the main controller, and base states and availability on that.

Comment: Cool, I may have to use child states then. As far as authorization checks, I guess that was a bad example. What I'm really trying to do is retrieve account information for a user. So let's say they sign in, a cookie is created, they close the browser, and they come back later. They're still signed in technically, but we have to retrieve their account data once again. That retrieval is something I'd like to use a resolve for, and I need to ensure whatever requested view does not render until that data is resolved. Would you still say that functionality should live in a service?

Comment: Ah right, well as a rule of thumb I put all API-like calls in a service. The router should just do routing. What I used before was something like:  .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      controller: function($state, $cookieStore) {
        if($cookieStore.get('token')) {
          $state.go('app.substate-of-app');
        } else {
          $state.go('pub.home'); // or login screen
        }
      }
    })

Comment: Ah yes! Services with methods to provide nice JavaScript interfaces to talking to the API...yep, I'm using those :)

Comment: One suggestion for Hydra's example would be to make the base app state (or whatever it's called) `abstract` so that it's obvious that it's not meant to be entered directly.

Answer (score 1):

It all eventually depend on how you organize your routes, since you can inherit routes and provide resolve clause for each child and the parents, but you also have stateChangestart  stateChangeSuccess events that will allow you to do something similar to that. for further assistance please provide samples of your routes

Comment: Yep, I'm using `$stateChangestart ` now. But the problem is, I need to actually delay the rendering of a view until data requests resolve, and the only way I can think of is to use a resolve against every route.

Comment: can you post  route samples?